# Transparent app drawer background on a rooted phone

Tags: cyanogenmod, custom-roms, customization, xposed-framework

I tried to achieve this using Xposed FW's Gravity Box, Xblast tools but was unable to find this setting. Is there any app or mod that allows us to achieve a transparent/semi transparent app drawer background (the kind on the Google Experience Launcher). Please note that I want to achieve this **without using another launcher** or [decompile trebuchet.apk](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2061028).
I'm using Legacy Xperia CM 10.2.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be looking for Module [**Xposed GEL Settings**](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.theknut.xposedgelsettings) (also available on the Play Store [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.theknut.xposedgelsettings)).
It is just a re-post, but I believe this is an elaborate and clear tutorial for achieving transparent app drawer background tweak:
[Change Lollipop App Drawer Background](https://forums.oneplus.net/threads/xposed-tweak-change-lollipop-app-drawer-background.298549/)